# How to make my oracle procedure to wait till I get response from called servlet?

Tags: oracle

We are using below procedure to call a servlet which will create a 'PDF Report' by fetching records from a table. Since that table is huge in size (approx. 40GB) it takes 15 minutes to create that PDF report. Till that time i need to run a loop to check whether the servlet request has been successfully completed.

If it is successful then we need to call a procedure which will send a mail with the generated PDF file attachment.

Issue: Now before getting/checking response this procedure is calling the Send Mail procedure. So mail is going without attachment.

Please give me some idea to solve this issue.

```
    PROCEDURE batch_generate_report_prc
  (
  pi_date     IN   DATE,
  po_filename OUT  VARCHAR2
   )
IS
  p_paramval       VARCHAR2(500);
  p_filename    VARCHAR2(500);
  v_url            VARCHAR2(2000);
  p_key            VARCHAR2(500);
  p_spool                  VARCHAR2(500);
  p_rep_seq           NUMBER;
  p_strfilename       VARCHAR2(500);
  v_run_report      VARCHAR2 (2000);
  vn_block         NUMBER(5,2);
  Po_status           NUMBER;
  vs_errmsg              VARCHAR2(500);

 BEGIN
  BEGIN

     Po_status := 1;

     vn_block := 10;
     SELECT lrepseq
     INTO p_rep_seq
     FROM com_reports_m
     WHERE strrepname = 'NBR050';

     vn_block := 11;
     p_paramval := pi_date || '~' || 'SYSTEM';
     -- p_paramval := p_paramval||'~'||c1_rec.strcompanycd;
     v_url :=
        com_rep_let_output_pkg.om_build_url_fnc (p_rep_seq,
                                                 p_paramval,
                                                 3,
                                                 'repletbatchprocess',
                                                 NULL,
                                                 p_strfilename
                                                );
     vn_block := 12;
     SELECT strparamvalue
     INTO p_key
     FROM om_configuration
     WHERE nparamkey = 78;

     vn_block := 13;
     SELECT strparamvalue
     INTO p_spool
     FROM om_configuration
     WHERE nparamkey = 61;

     vn_block := 14;
     --DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_url);
     p_filename :=
           'NBR050'
        || '_SYSTEM_'
        || TO_CHAR (pi_date, 'DD-MON-RRRR')
        || TO_CHAR (SYSTIMESTAMP, '_HH24MISSFF6')
        || '.pdf';
     v_url :=
           v_url
        || '&cmdkey='
        || p_key
        || '&P_FILE_FORMAT=1&DESFORMAT=PDF&DESTYPE=FILE&'
        || '&desname='
        || p_spool
        || p_filename;
  --DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_url);                              --Run the report

   vn_block := 14;
   UTL_HTTP.set_transfer_timeout (5000);
   v_run_report := UTL_HTTP.request (v_url);

   EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
     po_filename := NULL;
     vs_errmsg := 'Error Occured while Generating Excep Rep NBR050 ' || SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 110);
     com_insert_exception_prc
                      (11,
                       992,
                       SYSDATE,
                       'MAIL',
                       NULL,
                          '9 Error occurred at block no='
                       || vn_block
                       || ' in Mail process while executing BPM Report NR050:'
                       || ' '
                       || SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 110)
                      );
       --dbms_output.put_line(SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 110));
      Po_status := 2;
  END;
  --Added by Muktad For Serch at FE.
  IF Po_status = 1
  THEN

     INSERT INTO COM_CONTACT_HST (lcontactseq,lrepseq,dtcontact,nstatus,dtstatus,strfilename,leventseq,strcreatedby,DTCREATED)
     VALUES
     (COM_CONTACT_HST_SEQ.nextval,p_rep_seq,pi_date,Po_status,pi_date,p_filename,9,'BATCH',sysdate);

     COMMIT;

  END IF;

  BEGIN --This sends mail but doubt ful to get the details how it sent.
     BATCH_MAIL_SEND_REPORT_PRC(pi_date,p_filename,po_status);
  END;

  po_filename := p_filename;

  EXCEPTION

  WHEN OTHERS
  THEN

     po_filename := NULL;

     com_insert_exception_prc
     (
         pi_nmoduleid       =>   10
        ,pi_nprocessid      =>   877
        ,pi_dtprocess       =>   SYSDATE
        ,pi_strpolnbr       =>   'Mail'
        ,pi_npolcheckdigit  =>   NULL
        ,pi_strerrordesc    =>   '10 Unable to send mail in batch_mail_pkg.batch_generate_report_prc at block no :'||vn_block||' Oracle Error :'||Substr(Sqlerrm,1,100)
        ,pi_nmessagelevel   =>   0
     );
    END;
```

Comment: A stored procedure that calls a servlet and another one that sends emails? No shit, the world is definitely ending in 2012.

Comment: Does the HTTP request finish successfully ( ie return a 200 HTTP response code ) ?

Comment: Should this really be a 'java' question? Does it really matter that the service providing the pdf is a java servlet? It could be anything as far as this code is concerned, couldn't it?

Comment: did u try UTL_HTTP.begin_request and get_response?  See http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/RetrievingHTMLandBinariesIntoTablesOverHTTP.php

Answer (score 1):

Never used this utl_http thing, but (according to [this UTL_HTTP reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96612/u_http.htm)) aren't you supposed to wait for a response with `utl_http.get_response`?

Answer (score 0):

In your send email procedure, check for the presence of the generated PDF, if the file exists then we know the servlet has completed processing the request.

Comment: Hi, what is the code to check for the presence of the file generated?